# How to include blank view in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

i design a login view. I want to insert a fragment layout which is placed at the center of parent view. I hard code to input some fragment layout to make this effect. But, does there exist better way to do this.

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_frame" 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"                
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/editUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"   
        android:padding="10dp"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="password"               
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</TableRow> 
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"      
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"        
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:password="true"                
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row5"          
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkRememberPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="rememberme"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row6"            
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"/>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Wow! i think layout_marginTop is very useful =].